# tracking pull/release of collection view for pull to refresh functionality

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, pull-to-refresh

I'm implementing Pull-to-refresh functionality for collectionView .i want to update the data only on release of collectionView. How can i do that.The problem i'm facing is that app is crashing  with error "array beyond bounds" when i reload the collectionView when the CollectionView is pulled.

Comment: Can you post code? This could be any array.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array'